# How do you compose tasks in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to build a custom task for building our project in our continuous integration environment. It is a set of steps along the lines of

1. Send build started message to a chat room
2. Compile templates
3. Run npm tests
4. Run jshint
5. Compile
6. Build application artifact
7. Upload artifact to our deployment server
8. Run tests
9. Send test results to our deployment server
10. Send build results message to chat room

Note that step 10 should be done if any steps fail, and the message should be customized depending on which step failed, e.g. if step 5 fails it should say "Compilation failed", if step 8 fails it should say how many tests were run and how many failed.

To make things extra interesting this is a multi project build, so when running tests and publishing results it should run all the tests and publish aggregated results.

To make things even more interesting, the npm tests, jshint and artifact only really make sense in the `webapp` subproject, where the Javascript lives and the web server resides.

I've been looking at sbt-release for inspiration, but I'm stymied on how to take the value produced by one task and use it in the next one, how to run tasks in aggregate and get the produced values (I see a method in `Extracted` to run aggregated tasks, but it doesn't give produced values), how to run tasks in a subproject and get the produced value, and how to do the error handling.

So far I've tried two approaches

```
npmTest.result.value match {                                                                    
  case Inc(inc) =>                                                                              
    println(inc)                                                                                
  case Value(res) => Def.taskDyn {                                                              
    (executeTests in Test).result.value match {                                                 
      case Inc(inc) =>                                                                          
        println(inc)                                                                            
      case Value(res) =>                                                                        
        println(res)                                                                            
    }                                                                                           
  }
```

The problem with the above is that `executeTests` is always run, even if `npmTest` fails. And none of the `println`s are executed.

```
npmTest.result.                                                                                    
 flatMap {-                                                                                       
   case Inc(inc) =>                                                                               
     task { println(inc) }                                                                        
   case Value(res) =>-                                                                            
     (executeTests in Test).result.                                                               
       flatMap {                                                                                  
         case Inc(inc) =>                                                                         
           task { println(inc) }                                                                  
         case Value(res) =>                                                                       
           task { println(res) }                                                                  
       }                                                                                          
 }
```

This one doesn't compile because `(executeTasks in Test)...` produces an `Initialize[Task[Unit]]` value and a `Task[Unit]` is required.

Is there a way to accomplish this with sbt?

Comment: Just a thought: you might consider just writing a shell script. Is there any strict need for this to all happen with the framework of sbt?

Comment: As written, the question is awfully broad. It's hard to know how to answer other than to say read the manual, and if you get stuck on something specific, open one or more questions here and show your code.

Comment: We are currently using a bit of a hacked up shell script. The problem with that is that the interesting information, e.g did compilation fail? how many tests ran/failed? are not as easily available. What I've tried to do so far is something along the lines of `sendBuildStart.flatMap((compile in Compile).result.flatMap { case Inc(inc) => sendCompileFailure(inc); case Value(_) => (test in Test).result.flatMap { case Inc(inc) => sendTestFailed(inc); case Value(_) => ....` unfortunately nothing seems to get run.

Comment: I've tried doing similar with the macros, like `sendBuildStart.result.value match { case Inc(inc) => println(); case Value(_) => (compile in Compile).result.value match { case Inc(inc) => sendCompileFailure(inc); case Value(_) => (test in Test).result.value match { case Inc(inc) => sendTestFailed(inc); case Value(testReport) => ...` but it seems like the inner tasks are *always* executed, even if a higher level one fails.

Comment: how to execute tasks conditionally using the 0.13 dsl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42915843/redefine-an-sbt-task-conditional-on-a-setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution that allows you to use good old `flatMap` and `map` to compose tasks.

```
sealed abstract class Step[A] {
  def run: Def.Initialize[Task[Result[A]]]
  def map[B](f: A => B): Step[B]
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Step[B]): Step[B]
}

object Step {
  val thisProjectRef = settingKey(Keys.thisProjectRef)
  val clean = taskKey(Keys.clean)
  val compile = taskKey(Keys.compile.in(Compile))
  val assembly = taskKey(sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin.autoImport.assembly)

  private[this] def apply[A](task: Def.Initialize[Task[Result[A]]]): Step[A] =
    new Step[A] {
      val run = task

      def map[B](f: A => B): Step[B] =
        apply[B](Def.taskDyn {
          run.value match {
            case Inc(inc) => Def.task(Inc(inc): Result[B])
            case Value(a) => Def.task(Value(f(a)))
          }
        })

      def flatMap[B](f: A => Step[B]): Step[B] =
        apply[B](Def.taskDyn {
          run.value match {
            case Inc(inc) => Def.task(Inc(inc): Result[B])
            case Value(a) => Def.task(f(a).run.value)
          }
        })
    }

  def task[A](t: Def.Initialize[Task[A]]): Step[A] =
    apply(t.result)

  def taskKey[A](t: TaskKey[A]): Step[A] =
    apply(Def.task(t.result.value))

  def settingKey[A](s: SettingKey[A]): Step[A] =
    apply(Def.task(s.value).result)
}
```

Then you can define your tasks as

```
    rainicornPublish <<= {
      val result = 
        for {
          ass <- Step.assembly
          juri <- uploadAssemblyTask(ass)
          to <- runAllTests
          _ <- finish(ass, juri, to)
        } yield (ass, to)

      Def.task(result.run.value match {
        case Inc(inc) => throw new RainicornException(None)
        case Value(v) => v
      })
    }
```

And each task will happen in sequence, just as you would expect.

Comment: @pfn That's the approach I wound up taking. I'll update my answer.